# Getting time of special timezone in UNIX-time format. Android

Tags: java, android, time, unix-timestamp

I need to get current time in UNIX format. But with `System.currentTimeMillis()` i get time, which is not time of my timezone. (My timezone is "GMT+3")

I want to convert my local time to UNIX format. How can i do that in Android?

I want to find simple and short way of it.

P.S.: In Android i can't use LocalDateTime.

Comment: What about Joda?  Can you use that?

Comment: @Zoe it's not duplicate. So explain me how can i get unix time from SimpleDateFormat. Your duplicate doesn't contain my case.

Comment: UNIX time does not have time zones. It is the same everywhere on the world.

Comment: @JoeC i'm beginner in the android development and don't know all ways to do it. I think, i can use it. Can u explain me this way in more details?

Comment: Of course it doesn't contain your **exact** case. No questions ever do unless you ask it yourself. It is a duplicate because it can be changed (with small changes) to handle your case.

Comment: If you're asking me to write it for you, that's not going to happen.  I suggest you do some research, make an attempt, and come back with a more specific question if necessary.

Comment: @Zoe i can't find this "small changes". I ask this question to find an EXACT case. Why can't i do that?

Comment: If you check the answer you see it gets converted to a Date. From the date you can use `getTime()` to get the time in millis from the epoch. That is why it is close enough to be a duplicate

Comment: so add the `java.util.TimeZone`'s offset to your `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: @Zoe `getTime()` are identical `System.currentTimeMillis()`. You are wrong.

Comment: @pskink i don't understand, how can i do that. Give me example pls.

Comment: if your zone is (GMT+3) then add 3600 * 3 * 1000 to the value returned by `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: @MichaelAbyzov getTime gets the current time in milliseconds in a given timezone. Works with date and hook that up with a Calendar to get the current time and you have the current time in millis without having to do maths as proposed by pskink

Comment: just see `java.util.TimeZone` documentation to see how to get the offset

Comment: Ok guys, but `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3")).getTime().getTime()` are equals to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. It doesn't consider my timezone. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @pskink can you gimme an example of getting current unix time in my timezone without mathematics? I can't find it in documentation.

Comment: without mathematics? no, you have to add `long` and `int` values

Comment: @pskink i don't understand you. Is there no way to do it, except adding 3600 * 3 * 1000 ??? I don't believe

Comment: @Zoe gimme a Working example of your solutions. I can't find a way of it.

Comment: just add `currentTimeMillis()` to your current `TimeZone`'s  offset - this is one addition of `long` and `int` value - why dont you read `java.util.TimeZone` documentation to see how to get the offset ?

Comment: Currenttimemillis is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00Z - January 1st 1970 at midnight in UTC). This value is "absolute": right now everywhere in the world are in the same instant (with the same millis value). But this value can correspond to a different date and time in different places. What exactly is the value that you expect?

Comment: Yeap, i've read documentation more attentively and found solution. Thanks @pskink and other guys for your feedback!

Comment: @JoeC No, the Joda-Time library is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). The team advises migrating to the java.time classes. Much of the java.time  functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, a project led by the same man who led both Joda-time and java.time, Stephen Colebourne. Further adapted for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. So no need to recommend Joda-Time any longer.

Comment: `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Istanbul" ) ).toString()` > `2017-10-09T09:03:35.495+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]` — See [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hOY94c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed adding an offset of my timezone. Function below was exactly what i wanted!

```
public static long getCurrentTimeInUnixFormat(){
    return (System.currentTimeMillis()
            + TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3").getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())) / 1000;
}
```

Comment: so it wasn't that hard, was it? reading some official docs makes miracles! ;-)